# Delegate to a generator in python 3.6+ asyncio coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio

In python 3.3 I can do the following

```
def _gen():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i

def gen():
    yield from _gen()

for i in gen():
    print(i)

>>> 0
>>> 1
>>> 2
```

Can I do the same within a python 3.6 asyncio coroutine? (Warning, contrived example)

```
async def _gen():
    for i in range(3):
        yield await get_num(i) # get_num is a coroutine

async def gen():
    yield from _gen() # Syntax error!

for i in gen():
    print(i)
```

I need to define `gen` as

```
async def gen():
    async for i in _gen():
        yield i
```

But it seems there should be a way to delegate to the other coroutine as we could with `yield from`

Comment: It's [not yet implemented](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#asynchronous-yield-from).

Comment: @Vincent what indicates that it will be implemented at some point?

Comment: Because it would make sense. The limitation here is that it would require some serious effort as PEP 525 points out, and the gain is quite limited.

Answer (score 2):

`yield from` is not supported in Python 3.6 due to the reasons [described in PEP 525](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#asynchronous-yield-from):

> While it is theoretically possible to implement `yield from` support for
>   asynchronous generators, it would require a serious redesign of the
>   generators implementation.
>
> `yield from` is also less critical for asynchronous generators, since
>   there is no need provide a mechanism of implementing another
>   coroutines protocol on top of coroutines. And to compose asynchronous
>   generators a simple async for loop can be used:
>
> ```
> async def g1():
>     yield 1
>     yield 2
>
> async def g2():
>     async for v in g1():
>         yield v
> ```

Comment: I find it hard to understand why `yield from` would require any kind of change to how asynchronous generators are _implemented_. Couldn't `yield from` inside `async def` simply desugar to an `async for` equivalent of the [regular `yield from` desugaring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics)?

Comment: @user4815162342 I believe asynchronous generators (and plain ones) are implemented in C, not Python. Code by link you provided is probably showcase, not real part of CPython source code.

Comment: Of course, the code only shows the desugaring that could be performed by the compiler, and the actual implementation is in the bytecode evaluator. But the PEP claims that the _implementation_ of async generators would need to change, without giving a reason. After all, `yield from` could just be syntactic sugar for the kind of loop shown in `g2`.